# how to obtain a generalized Morse function out of a fiber bundle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, fiber-bundles, morse-theory

Let $M\to E\to B$ be a smooth fiber bundle. In "Parametrized Morse Theory and Its Applications,(Proceedings of the ICM, 1990)",  K. Igusa says that if dim $B$$<$dim $M$, then, there exists a smooth function $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ such that, when restricted to the fibers, is a generalized Morse function (i.e. a smooth function with only non degenerate critical points and birth-death singularities). For the proof of this fact he refers to "On the homotopy type of the space of generalized Morse functions (Topology, Vol 23, No2., 1984)". There he proves that if $N$ is an $n$-dimensional smooth manifold, then there is an $n$-connected map between the space of such functions on $N$ and certain infinite loop space $\Omega^{\infty}S^{\infty}(BO\wedge N_+)$.

My question is, how come does the connectivity of the latter map imply the existence of the generalized Morse $f$?. Perhaps more generally, is there a canonical way to assign such a function to the total space of a fiber bundle?